# jQuery select element by using variable as id passed from the argument

Tags: jquery, ajax

i got error jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #
    at Function.ga.error (jquery.min.js:2),can someone help me. thank you in advance

```
function showmore(id)
 {
  jQuery.ajax({
       type: "POST",  
       url:'showmore.php',
       data:{action:'true'},
       success:function(html) {
        jQuery('#' + id).html(html);
       }

  });

 }
```

Comment: Could you please explain the context of your error. ie. What you are trying to do? I suppose you are trying to validate a form. Tip: Try using un-minified js during development if possible. so jQuery.js

Comment: i want server to reutn html and assigning that html  to div tag using id